# MVC why new added column miss display data

Tags: model-view-controller

I'm really new to MVC,
I used the database first to import a table from local sql server. I use the entityFrameWork and  just keep all the default features. After I add controller and view. I go back to my sql server and add another column called DateofBirth(datetime). I go to the MVC, 
I put DateofBirth in the model and the view(in create view). However, the data kick back as all '1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM +00:00' instead of the actual data.
Any possible reason for that?

Person Model:

```
    partial class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        this.appts = new HashSet<appt>();
    }

    public int P_Id { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateofBirth { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<appt> appts { get; set; }
}
```

Person View(index):

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.P_Id)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateofBirth)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

          foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.P_Id)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateofBirth)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.P_Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.P_Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.P_Id })
    </td>
          </tr>
              }

             </table>
```

controller:

```
namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
[Authorize(Users="aaron")]
public class personController : Controller
{
    private dumb_so_dumbEntities db = new dumb_so_dumbEntities();

    // GET: /person/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Persons.ToList());
    }

    // GET: /person/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Person person = db.Persons.Find(id);
        if (person == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(person);
    }

    // GET: /person/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: /person/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="P_Id,LastName,FirstName,Address,City")] Person person)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Persons.Add(person);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(person);
    }

    // GET: /person/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Person person = db.Persons.Find(id);
        if (person == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(person);
    }




    // POST: /person/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="P_Id,LastName,FirstName,Address,City")] Person person)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
        return View(person);
    }






    // GET: /person/Delete/

    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Person person = db.Persons.Find(id);
        if (person == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(person);
    }

    // POST: /person/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Person person = db.Persons.Find(id);
        db.Persons.Remove(person);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please update your question with some of the code, like the controller class.

Comment: @NeerPatel  I add some codes. Thanks

Comment: @ShakeAaron can you post your controller?

Comment: @NeerPatel Yes. Thank you so much

Comment: @NeerPatel I fixed it! I think the problem was I need to update the database. I updated at the model.edmx Diagram by right click the table-update model by database